# Why would we ever have the need to estimate a population mean if we know the population standard deviation?

Tags: statistics

We had to compute the population’s mean to get it’s standard deviation.  Therefore we have no need to estimate it or do sampling.

If you look at Figure 7–8 in this link, when would step 1 ever be applicable? Seems like we would always skip this step.

https://rampages.us/meraki/2015/11/01/confidence-interval-choosing-the-confidence-level/

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Even though the formula for the population standard deviation involves the population mean, you could know what the population standard deviation is without knowing what the population mean is. Consider for example the family of distributions $N(\mu,1)$ as $\mu$ ranges over the real numbers. In principle you could know in advance that your distribution is of this form but not know what $\mu$ is. (In practice you usually know neither the population mean nor the population standard deviation, however.)